# Creating filter with multiple file name

Tags: java, swt

I wanted to create filter in java for browse file dialogue it should allow only either abc.exe or xyz.exe 
I am using swt.widgets.FileDialog

currently I am filtering for *.exe with following string

```
 String[] extensionFilter = { "*.exe" }; 
 fileDialog .setFilterExtensions(extensionFilter);
```

How can I change this to allow only only abc.exe xyz.exe?

It should search for abc.exe and xyz.exe

example: When you allow multiple extensions(.exe,.dat) it will search for all files with that(.exe,.dat) extensions similarly I want to search for abc.exe and  xyz.exe

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean `string.matches("(abc|xyz)\\.exe")` ??

Comment: If you are going to use swing to browse file dialog, then you can use File Choosers. It has filter files facility. [File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Please be more specific than "browse file dialogue".  Which file dialog class are you using?  java.awt.FileDialog, javax.swing.JFileChooser, or javafx.stage.FileChooser?

Comment: I am using  swt.widgets.FileDialog

Comment: @Ganesh i have edited my answer. Review it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858468/creating-filter-with-complete-file-name/24858508#24858508

Comment: @Ganesh Try example 28 in http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** use `setFilterExtension(String[])`, however you have to know how to format the String:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Choose");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell);
            dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "abc.exe;xyz.exe" });

            System.out.println(dialog.open());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

The single String `"abc.exe;xyz.exe"` tells it that both these are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] extensionFilter = { "abc.exe","xyz.exe" };
```

Comment: I tried it but what I'll get is I have to select first either abc.exe or xyz.exe then it searches only particular exe. what I want is It should search both abc.exe and xyz.exe . like how we will allow select extentions like .mp3,.mp4,.wav.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setFilterNames**

Which is explained [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FFileDialog.html)
**It allows String type array variable only. No need to bother about regEx**

```
 String[] extensionFilter = { "abc.exe;xyz.exe" };

 fileDialog.setFilterExtensions( extensionFilter );
```

Comment: @Ganesh Try Code example 28 in http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog

Comment: `setFilterNames` sets the names to be shown for the extension filters, it does not filter the file names. JavaDoc: Sets the names that describe the filter extensions which the dialog will use to filter the files it shows to the argument, which may be null.
Each name is a user-friendly short description shown for its corresponding filter. The names array must be the same length as the extensions array.